# jquery: merging text value and function

Tags: jquery

Just trying to add some text before function's result.

```
onClick="$('#itempriceqty0').clone().appendTo('#itempricewrapper').attr('id', $('#itempricewrapper').children().length-5+1)"
```

So I need to add text: itempriceqty right before this function $('#itempricewrapper').children().length-5+1. So ending result for attr change will be like: itempriceqty3.

Tried this, but did not work:

```
onClick="$('#itempriceqty0').clone().appendTo('#itempricewrapper').attr('id', 'itempriceqty'+$('#itempricewrapper').children().length-5+1)''"
```

Thanks.

Comment: If you are using jQuery you should **NEVER** use `onClick`.  You should be binding these events with the [`click()`](http://api.jquery.com/click) method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for this?

```
onClick="$('#itempriceqty0').clone().appendTo('#itempricewrapper').attr('id', 'itempriceqty' + ($('#itempricewrapper').children().length - 5 + 1))"
```

Your quotes were a little messed up and you want some parentheses around the arithmetic to make sure the arithmetic is done before the string concatenation.

Comment: Although you might of fixed his quoting problems, any suggestion that still involves using `onclick` in the current age of HTML/JS development doesn't sit well in my book.

Comment: @gnarf: I'd agree but I don't know what sorts of constraints the OP is working under, there are situations where old-school onclick attributes are all you have.

Comment: What other ways you think are more progressive for "current age" when user needs to click plus sign to clone input elements?

Comment: @Radio: `$('some-selector').click(function() { ... });` would be more modern and jQuery-ish. You'd just need to figure out which selector to use, usually you'd just add a specific CSS class to the plus sign elements and say `$('.clone-inputs').click(function() { ... });`.

Comment: @MU: thanks for advise, looks better, but I think it does not make it way too progressive to old-school onClick="function()".

Comment: @mu is too short: tried to implement your way of handling clicks. worked on most elements, but stuck on one, not sure why. Please help. $('div[id^=itempriceminus]').click(function() { alert('test'); }); . Firebug shows that all ids are correct, for example: <div id="itempriceminus3" class="big bold">div3</div><div id="itempriceminus4" class="big bold">div4</div><div id="itempriceminus5" class="big bold">div5</div>

Comment: Sorry, got it. click() cannot handle new ajax content, used live() instead.